# How to delete all the open files in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, recycle-bin

I have opened many files in notepad++ window tabs. Is there any way(or any plugin) in npp to quickly delete all the open files?

I don't want to go to each tab, right click and use `Move to Recycle Bin`, since there are thousands of open files so I'm looking for a shortcut to delete all these open files in one shot. Could some please suggest if there is any way to do it?

Comment: “there are thousands of open files” Really?

Comment: @Toto yes, a lot of open files, I used find in files and opened all the files which matched a specific text. Now I want to delete the matched files.

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1686). Why don't you write a small script in your favorite scripting language?

Comment: @Toto Nope. I'm asking a simple and clear question - How to bulk delete open files in NPP, This is not a XY problem.

Comment: The answer is as simple and clear, you can't.

Comment: @Toto thanks for your answer, I'd also like to listen from others

Comment: @Toto You probably can, using [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). But the OP will have to try and write his own script.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Not sure a Npp PythonSscript can delete all opened files.

Comment: @Toto It can save a file so it can probably close a file and delete it.

Comment: @DavidPostill: As far as I know, Python scripts act in the current tab only, they can't save, close or delete files opened in other tabs. That said, I'm not completly sure...

Comment: @Todo Perhaps you should read the documentation then "notepad is the object for everything to do with Notepad++ itself, not the text in the document. Things like opening and saving files, **selecting different tabs**, converting formats, running plugin commands and so on."

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment not an answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough "reputation" to add comments...

My suggestion is to use another tool: Total Commander would be an excellent candidate for your task: https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm

It's so easy in TC to search for files <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> containing your specific text, just check the "Find text" field <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then when search is done select "Feed to listbox" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and finally Select All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> them

[image]

Note: if you want to preview any of your files before deletion just <kbd>F3</kbd> over them and you can quickly view the content (and while viewing, keep pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> to jump to all occurrences where you searched text was found)

Comment: OP didn't ask for another tool, they want to do the job with Notepad++.

Comment: Yeap, I know the question was about N++, but instead to complicate life with Python scripting the task can be achieved simpler in other ways, just my opinion: use the right tool for the task. TC is only one way (which I use) but there are many other alternatives even open source to choose
https://alternativeto.net/software/total-commander/?platform=windows

Comment: They don't want to delete “some files” but only those that are opened in Notepad++. How do you know what are these files in Total Commander?

Comment: As the post mentions: have to repeat the **same** search with TC like the one which was done in N++: the results should be the same...

Comment: You're assuming there is a pattern for searching files to be delete, may be it's true, but it is not said in question. They said they have thousands files opened, they never said those files have common characteristics.

Comment: Quote from OP's comment: "I used find in files and opened all the files which matched a specific text"

Comment: Well, wait and see for OP. I'll give you my vote if OP accepts your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it someway like this:

- Make a copy of %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml
- Open the copy in an advanced text editor (Notepad++ is fine too)
- Do a regular expression search & replace to get rid of everything but the filenames
- Add "del " to the beginning of every line
- Save as a .bat file
- Run the .bat file

Answer (score -2):

Please go to this path - C:\Users{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup and remove the files which are not needed

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: Please read the full question and comments before answering. Backup folder contains only the unsaved files open in Notepad++. VVK wanted to delete all existing files that are currently open in Notepad++.